# Different types of lists

Tags: java

Hello I am studying Java and I am just confused about a question that keeps coming up in my exams.

We are told to use a class for our collections.

Usually in my main class I just make an arraylist of the type I need like bank accounts or whatever. But I think we are supposed to make a class for all our data. I tried this and made them static and have the class abstract because I don't need to make copies of the class itself.

What I want to know is why don't people just make a list type that can do everything an arraylist and list can do in one, why is there different types? What are the benifits of having different types? Ps does a collection just mean a class for all your data?

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you asking why there are multiple implementations of List, like ArrayList and LinkedList? Any code example that you could share, with a clear explanation of what you don't understand?

Comment: An `ArrayList` *is* a class for collections - it implements `List`, which implements `Collection`.

Comment: Is it good practise to have all your lists in one class?

Comment: @Sam: a typical, real-life program has hundreds or thousands of classes. And obviously, several of them use one or several lists. It sometimes makes sense to have several lists in a single class, and sometimes it doesn't. It all depends on the concrete problem to solve. What is your concrete problem?

Comment: In every exam we get a uml diagram of the classes to do. One is called OnjectList that contains a array of objects. I dont see why this makes sense why it is not in the main class for example. Also the array must be set as a default size that the user can set using the constructor. But I would think the array would not be set as new until the default value is set. so myarray[DEFAULT_VALUE]; until in the constructor it would be set the default value then have myarray[DEFAULT_VALUE] = new array(); does this make sense?

Answer (score 14):

Every List has its own usage:

- ArrayList behaves like a Resizable-array
- LinkedList could be used as a FIFO queue
- Stack obviously is a stack (LIFO)

Here's the javadoc for list:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html

Comment: stack is a stack ? stack is LIFO.

Comment: Yea.. but I assume most people know stack equals to LIFO.  In most cases, we simply say stack when we mean LIFO. Right?